# Hibernate / @ElementCollection and @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm struggling with Hibernate and can not find a working solution to do what i want. It's for a webservice btw.

Short explanation :
I have a list of objects (Composant) which has to be embedded in the main object (Projet). I want to persist both in my database (PostgreSQL). To do so I set them as follow :

My first table is named T_PROJET
It containes the id marked as PRJ_NAME
The list which I'm struggling on ComponentList
And an expiration date PRJ_DATE

And for the smaller object the table is named T_COMPOSANT.
Got an automatically generated id : COMP_ID.
A name COMP_NOM
A value COMP_MONTANT
And a priority COMP_IMPORTANCE

On my HMI, I can create a Projet with at least one Composant but i can add more (up to 5 Composant for a Projet), and the Composants will be saved as a List.

Here's a JSON example of what I tend to produce on my HMI :

```
{
"name":"Example",
"dateLimite":"2018-08-08",
"composant_1": {
    "name":"Vol",
    "montant": 1200,
    "importance":1
},
"composant_2": {
    "name":"Truc",
    "montant": 1200,
    "importance":1
},
"composant_3": {
    "name":"Bidule",
    "montant": 1200,
    "importance":1
},
"composant_4": {
    "name":"Machin",
    "montant": 1200,
    "importance":1
},
"composant_5": {
    "name":"Wesh",
    "montant": 1200,
    "importance":1
}
}
```

Here's the main object "Projet":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PROJET")
@XmlRootElement
public class Projet implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;
private List<Composant> composants;
private Date dateLimite;

public Projet() {
    super();
}

public Projet(String name, List <Composant> composants, Date dateLimite) {
    this.name = name;
    this.composants = composants;
    this.dateLimite = dateLimite;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "PRJ_NOM", nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="T_COMPOSANT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COMP_ID"))
@Embedded
@Column(name="COMP_ID", nullable = true)
public List<Composant> getComposants() {
    return composants;
}

public void setComposants(List <Composant> composants) {
    this.composants = composants;
}

@Column(name="PRJ_DATE")
public Date getDateLimite() {
    return dateLimite;
}

public void setDateLimite(Date dateLimite) {
    this.dateLimite = dateLimite;
}
}
```

And the "Composant" :

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "T_COMPOSANT")
@XmlRootElement
public class Composant implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int composant_id;
private String name;

private int montant;

private int importance;

public Composant(){
    super();
}

public Composant(final int composant_id, final String name, final int montant, final int importance) {
    this.composant_id = composant_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.montant = montant;
    this.importance = importance;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "COMP_ID")
public int getComposant_id() {
    return composant_id;
}

public void setComposant_id(int composant_id) {
    this.composant_id = composant_id;
}



@Column(name = "COMP_NOM",nullable = true)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="COMP_MONTANT", nullable = true)
public int getMontant() {
    return montant;
}

public void setMontant(int montant) {
    this.montant = montant;
}

@Column(name = "COMP_IMPORTANCE", nullable = true)
public int getImportance() {
    return importance;
}

public void setImportance(int importance) {
    this.importance = importance;
}
}
```

At each try I get a " Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy" error.
I'm sure that I missed something about the @ElementCollection and @Embeddable annotations but can not figure out where exactly (went through my Antonio Goncalves' books but no answer or I just can't read correctly).
Any idea on what i should look for?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ElementCollection`/`@CollectionTable` are probably conflicting with `@Embedded`/`@Column`.

`@Embedded` defines an embedded object where `@ElementCollection` defines a list of embedded objects.

`@Column` defines a column where `@CollectionTable` defines the join of the collection.

**If you don't need `Composant` as an entity :**

1. Remove `@Embedded` and `@Column` from `getComposants()`
2. Remove `@Table` from `Composant` (it's already declared in `@CollectionTable`)

**If you need `Composant` as an entity :**

1. Remove `@ElementCollection`, `@CollectionTable`, `@Embedded` and `@Column` from `Projet#getComposants()`
2. Remove `@Embeddable` from `Composant`
3. Add `@Entity` to `Composant`
4. Add the annotations to `getComposants()`.

-

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "T_PROJET_COMPOSANT",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROJ_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COMP_ID"),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works fine with the second solution.